# how to select a specific record from a query in Coldfusion?

Tags: select, coldfusion, resultset

I'm trying to optimize a product search to be used on mobile devices using Coldfusion8/MySQL.

Right now the following happens:

```
1. user searches for "FOO"
2. Q1: search database for no of results
3. Q2: search again to get actual data for results FROM TO depending on pagination
4. user clicks details for a product
5. redo Q1 to get no of results
6. redo Q2 to get single result
7. use single result to query for product details (sizes, colors, pricings...)
```

I'm looking for a way to skip redoing Q1 and Q2, because the user picked a result from the resultset, so why should I rebuild the resultset again just to get a single result.

**Question**:
I guess the way would be to pass a variable indicating I'm only needing details of a record in an exinsting query. Say I have results 1-20 and I pass a variable "DETAIL" and an articlenumber "123", how would I select the matching record from an existing resultset = how can I select a specific record from a resultset?uery

**EDIT:**
So I think the only way for my case is to run the query the first time, store the results in Session.storage and then pick the respective record from the storage vs. re-running my initial search.

Query of Queries does not work, because my initial query is inside an cfinvoke method, so when it's done, it's gone and on the next pass through I cannot query the results of the last cfinvoke.

I also tried to store into my cfc variables scope. Also does not work, I guess for the same reason. I don't want to start using cfobject, because I'm still running CF8 and I'm reading a lot on how cfobject hampers performance.

Anyway. On my first query called "results", I'm now storing

```
<cfset Session.storate = results>
```

When I dump session storage I get:

```
catch - query
    CACHED: false 
    EXECUTIONTIME: 2031 
    SQL: SELECT a.*, p.ek, p.vk, p.x, p.y
        FROM arts a
    LEFT JOIN p ON 
            ...
            LEFT JOIN f ON 
            ... 
            WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
            AND 
            ... 20 conditions ...

    SQLPARAMETERS: [array]
    1) %402% 
    ... 20 parameters

    RESULTSET: 
     [Record # 1] 
        a: true
        style: 402
        price: 2.3
        currency: CHF
        ...
     [Record # 2] 
        a: true
        style: 402abc
        ...
```

My question would now be:

How can loop over **session.storage** and check for style? If found, this is my result, which I will build the detail view from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I follow, but if I am you could do a Query of Queries, which allows you query an existing query that ran on your page.

```
<cfquery name="getOneRecord" dbtype="query">
SELECT record
FROM originalqueryname
WHERE articlenumber = 123
</cfquery>
```

If you only need to retrieve one result this is probably the fastest way.

Comment: But say the user searches for FOO and query="getAllRecords" to show results from 1-20. When the user now wants to see details of record 17, I don't want to query again, but use the 17th record from the "getAllRecords" resultset. Do I just have to loop through the getAllRecords and check if articlenumber = 123. If yes, continue if no, do nothing?

Comment: I'm asking because my Query is painstakenly long and I since I already have record 17 in the resultset, why should I re-run the query to get the record with id 123

Comment: The query running above is a query of queries, which means it's not hitting your database again it's querying the query that already exists

Comment: if you just want to display the record you could do `#getAllRecords[columnname][17]#` where 17 represents the current row in the column.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. Will the original query still be available if I'm doing this inside a CFC, where I'm cfinvoke-ing my result handler. Probably not...

Comment: Well. nothing beats trying. I will repost, how I'm doing. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand why you would redo the search to get a single record.  If the user clicked on a details link that link should have some identifier back to the item selected.  I would then use that id to query the database and get product detail.  The original search query should only return relavent data to the results display.

Comment: hm. I'm still sitting on it... so you have my ear. Let me try.

Comment: Ok. I'm only pulling basic information on the first query, which is really a pain to get through MySQL (lot of Left Joins), lot of conditions. I want to avoid running this query over and over, so my idea was, if I ran it the first time, why can't I store the resultset (Session.storage = queryName), and then pull the detail basic record from it instead of rerunning the query itself. I need to do this, because the actual query is inside a cfinvoke, so when it's done, it's gone. I'm now wondering how to loop over the resultset... see my edit

Comment: It may be a pain but you are pulling data that is not needed. Let say for arguments sake that your query returns 20 columns of detail.  Your search results screen uses 5 of the columns, the detail screen uses the rest.  Now lets also stipulate that one of the columns is a text column that contains a large amount of data.   Lets say for example, the query returns 1000 items. You now have a large amount of data that will go unused.  All this extra data adds up.  Causes extra query time, extra processing time, extra ram usage.  It is generally just a very inefficient way to handle it.

Comment: I know it's a pain... :-) The database stores articles on ean/barcode basis, so a record will look like article, ean, info1, info2, info3. So an article may have any number of eans (sizes, colors, other criteria). First query I'm only pulling the basic article info (article, description...) and displaying this. When the user hits "details" I need to pull all article eans to create an order form. So my idea was if I have 20 results (articles), I store these, until the user does a new search. This way when he hits "details", I can select eans based on one of the stored records vs. re-querying

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is cachedwithin attribute.

Comment: If you could caches a query in Session scope yes, but in when user A searches for FOO and the results are cached, user B will hit a wall when searching for BAR and not getting any results.

Comment: If you do point #3 (the one you called Q2) first with a cachedwithin attribute, then when the same user does all the other queries, they are cached.